# Dropdown Categories used in form shows no results when all is selected

Tags: categories, dropdown

I'm using the wp_dropdown_categories twice in a search form, once for the categories and second for a custom taxonomy. When selecting the 'All" option no results are showing in the results page. The term_id of all categories is '0' as it is showing in the URL. When selecting a category AND a custom taxonomy from the dropdown it works fine.

Below is my query and my dropdowns:

```
if ( isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($_GET['manufacturer']) ) {

                $tax_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );
                array_push($tax_query,
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'  => 'manufacturers',
                        'field'     => 'term_id',
                        'terms'     => $_GET['manufacturer'],
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                        'field'     => 'term_id',
                        'terms'     => $_GET['cat'],
                    )
                );
            };

            if ( ( $_GET['cat'] == 0 ) || ( $_GET['manufacturer'] == 0 ) ) {
                $tax_query = ''
            };


                $query_args = array(
                    'post_type'         => 'yacht',
                    'meta_or_tax'       => true,
                    'tax_query'         => $tax_query,
                    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                    'meta_query'        => array(
                        'relation'      => 'AND',
                        array(
                         'key'          => 'yachts_loa_length_round',
                         'value'        => array($_GET['min_length'], $_GET['max_length']),
                         'compare'      => 'BETWEEN',
                         'type'         => 'NUMERIC',
                        ),
                        array(
                         'key'          => 'yachts_price',
                         'value'        => array($_GET['min_price'], $_GET['max_price']),
                         'compare'      => 'BETWEEN',
                         'type'         => 'NUMERIC',
                        ),
                        array(
                         'key'          => 'yachts_year',
                         'value'        => array($_GET['min_year'], $_GET['max_year']),
                         'compare'      => 'BETWEEN',
                         'type'         => 'NUMERIC',
                        )
                    )
                );

                $yacht_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

              $args = array(

                'orderby'            => 'menu_order',
                'show_option_all'    => pll__('All '),
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'         => 0,
                'exclude'            => -1,
                'name'               => 'cat',
                'class'              => 'form-select',
                'taxonomy'           => 'category',
              );

              wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>

              <?php

              $args = array(

                'orderby'            => 'menu_order',
                'show_option_all'    => pll__('All'),
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'         => 0,
                'exclude'            => -1,
                'name'               => 'manufacturer',
                'class'              => 'form-select',
                'taxonomy'           => 'manufacturers',
              );

              wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 isn't a valid term ID in a tax query. Don't add the category tax query parameters if the value is 0, which is equivalent to ignoring category. If you want only posts that are categorized (a category must be assigned, but it can be any category), then use the `EXISTS` operator.

```
$tax_query = '';

if( isset($_GET['cat']) && 0 != $_GET['cat'] ) {
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'category',
        'field'     => 'term_id',
        'terms'     => $_GET['cat']
    );
}

if( isset($_GET['manufacturer']) && 0 != $_GET['manufacturer'] ) {
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'manufacturers',
        'field'     => 'term_id',
        'terms'     => $_GET['manufacturers']
    );
}

// only add relation if both are set and non-zero
if( isset($_GET['manufacturer']) && 0 != $_GET['manufacturer'] && isset($_GET['cat']) && 0 != $_GET['cat'] ) {                
    $tax_query['relation'] = 'AND';
}

// query args for all queries
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'yacht',
    // other args...
);

// add tax query if it isn't empty
if( !empty( $tax_query ) ){
    $query_args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
}

$yacht_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Comment: @vagelis-katsiotis, this, and also the value for `field` should be `term_id` (not just `id`) according to [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: Thanx for the tips. All i want to do is when selecting the 'All' from the dropdowns to search through all categories and manufacturers, in other words to display all the yacht for all categories and all manufacturers

Comment: yes, that's what I understood from your question. If the values of either are 0, don't add those tax query parameters.

Comment: @Milo I've edited the post. Something like this maybe?

Comment: @vagelis - see edit above. untested, but should work!

Comment: @Milo great work!! Thank you! I've been working on this too long!